# Should my game states be JPanels?

Tags: java

I'm thinking about making a `StateManager` for my game. I want to know how to design it; that is, how to use a stack to push and pop states onto, and draw them to the screen.

For example, should each `State` be a `JPanel`? I want to make a `Menu`, preferably using `JButtons` if possible. I don't want to add them directly to the main panel because I don't want to have to constantly add and remove those buttons. Also, not all my states are going to be drawable, since I might have a state that contains a MouseListener to detect clicks.

Right now, I have an empty `State` class. My `Menu` class extends from that. My state stack is of the type State. Another design question: if in my `Menu` I click the "Play" button, should I just say something like `StateManager.push(new PlayState())` from the `Menu` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example, should each `State` be a `JPanel`?

It's generally better to [favor aggregation over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269496/inheritance-vs-aggregation). So your `State` class shouldn't *be* a `JPanel` (= *inherit* from it), but should probably *contain* a `JPanel` member for rendering its content.

That's because your states don't do rendering only, but also manage many other things. Better yet, if for some reason you need states without a `JPanel` this might mean less code changes.

> If in my `Menu` I click the "Play" button, should I just say something like `StateManager.push(new PlayState())` from the `Menu` class?

Sure! Just make sure your `StateManager` releases the reference to the `Menu` state when it's done switching to `PlayState`. Otherwise you'll get memory leaks.

Comment: Does every state have handle its own input, or is that done by the State Manager? For example, if I have HUD that is clickable, like "Pause," but my game involves clicking on tiles to move, how can I be sure that my State Manager will know to pause the game instead of move my player?

Comment: Well, as you've find out yourself, this is probably better to handle inputs directly in your state objects. If you've got overlapping states as you describe, enable input processing on the topmost state only.